# Shell script permission denied when conditional test

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Whenever I try to run my shell script, I'm getting an error under 4 different if tests.

```
script.sh 45: script.sh: : Permission denied
script.sh 52: script.sh: : Permission denied
script.sh 59: script.sh: : Permission denied
script.sh 324: script.sh: : Permission denied
```

I did a chmod 777 on my script so everyone has permissions to it.  The script is run like this:

```
./script fileToUse
```

Here is what those lines where it gave the error message looks like:

```
if ( "$VAR" == "Condition_1" )
then
    do stuff
elif ( "$VAR" == "Condition_2" )
then 
    do stuff
elif ( "$VAR" == "Condition_3" )
then 
    do stuff
else
    do stuff
fi
```

And the line of 324 looks like this:

```
if ( "$flagIsSet" -eq 0 )
then
    do stuff
fi
```

Any idea why I might be getting this error message and what it means?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I'd guess that your permission to access a ressource was denied. Hard to say more, given only pseudocode.

Comment: What shell are you running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parentheses run a subshell. Use brackets for comparisons:

```
if [ "$VAR1" = "Condition_1" ] ; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and instead I know get the error message ./script: 45 [: unexpected operator in place of the previous error for each of those lines

Comment: @nkon: OK, use single `=`.

Comment: Works!  But why?  I thought a single = sets a variable to a value?

Comment: Assignments are of the form `x=y` (no spaces on either side of the `=`. As an argument to the `[` command, it is the equality operator.

Comment: @chepner Thank you.  I wrote this script under OSX originally and then transferred it to my ubuntu box and it broke.  Under OSX the == was working with no issues, so that's why I was wondering why it is different.

Comment: When `bash` is used as `/bin/sh`, it allows you to use `==` in place of `=`. However, Ubuntu uses a different shell, `dash` as its `/bin/sh`, and it is not as forgiving.